# How to concatenate object properties in Typescript

Tags: typescript

My object looks like below

```
{street:"abc" , state:"xyz" , postalCode , "100"}
```

Is it possible to merge state and postal code as one property as follows

```
{street:"abc" , state: "xyz-100" }
```

Comment: This isn't "merging", it's just string concatenation.

Comment: @meagar yeah sorry for that. i want to concatenate the values of 2 properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const obj = { street: "abc", state: "xyz", postalCode: "100" };
obj.state += `-${obj.postalCode}`;
delete obj.postalCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it is,
use parts properties

"{ parts: [{path: 'Name'}, {path: 'LastName'}]}"